# How is profitability calculated?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

On the driver screen, there is a variety of profit statistics, profit per day and profit per mile. Mine always seem to be very negative as you can see from this picture

[image: picture]

What numbers are included when calculating profitability in Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can all depend on how slow you drive, how much fuel you use, or how much damage you receive. If you arrive late, you can lose money, too. I hope this helps.